# How to hide a button after letting the sound play until the end?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to hide a button after playing some audio that I previously recorded.

When I press the "stop button" everything goes well because the following code:

```
@IBAction func stopAllSounds(sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
        audioEngine.stop()
        stopButton.hidden = true
    }
```

My problem is when I let the audio finish. In this case, the "stop button" doesn't disappear.

To gave you a bit more of information, the following code is responsible for the "play button":

```
@IBAction func playSlow(sender: UIButton) {
    /* Good practise to stop audioPlayer */
    audioPlayer.stop()
    audioPlayer.rate = 0.5
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0.0
    /* Use audioPlayer here */
    audioPlayer.play()
    stopButton.hidden = false
}
```

After this I want the "stop button" to hide.
The `stopButton.hidden = false` in this function is to make the "stop button" visible when the sound is playing.

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioPlayer has a property for a delegate. In this delegate you have a method that is called once the audioPlayer sound is finished:

```
audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool)
```

So what you can do is have and object to be implement it's delegate `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` and implement that method hiding your button there.

```
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        stopButton.hidden = true;
    }
```